# Google Sheets: Match Function doesn't work on some values of time

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to create a function that would match a start time to an end time. I've edited down the sheet but this the error appears here, specifically in the Matching Function sheet: [Docs Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bNoLRCM7NBEZ2qvnf3MfeNLsCHPRElecOTp3S6hSWPs/edit?usp=sharing)

For some reason, the match function matches some of the time values and not others. A google search suggested a rounding error... but does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I changed formula to `=index('Sample List'!F:F, Match(round(A2,8),round('Sample List'!E:E,8),0))` and it worked in ColB. Great! But the same rounding of formula in ColC  `=Match(round(A2,8),round('Sample List'!E:E,8)` did not work. No idea!

Comment: Thanks for the help, it definitely worked with the index/match combo, but not match alone. Very strange, but if it works it works!

Comment: Could you work around the problem by forcing your time values to be text? eg. `=TEXT(B2, "HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this all seems to be due to some inconsistencies in how Google Sheets handles times.

(1) Using timevalue with a date time can give a different result to using it with just a time (although the documentation says that any date part is ignored):

[image]

(2) Using timevalue with just a time can give a different result to the original time (!)

[image]

It's fine as long as you do any processing the same way, so I suggest on your Sample List sheet to do the conversion from date time to time with:

```
=timevalue(right(B2,8))
```

(sometimes there are only 7 characters in the time part of the string, but Timevalue will ignore the leading blank).

and on your Matching Function sheet:

```
=match(timevalue(A2),'Sample List'!E:E,0)
```